# download multiple pdf using python

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

i try [this code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/downloading-files-web-using-python/) to download many pdf files:

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 30):
    r = requests.get('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), allow_redirects=True)

    open('file-risalah.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

but it only outputs a single pdf file. how to download each pdf file so that it can output as many file as in the iteration? 
i tied:

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 30):
    r = requests.get('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), allow_redirects=True)

    open('file-risalah'+str[i]+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

but its error

Comment: You're almost there! `str[i]` is not the correct syntax though. You used the correct syntax in `requests.get('...ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the name of the saved file each time.

```
open('file-risalah_'+str(i)+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that done when you download each pdf ?

Else you can try this

```
r = requests.get(str('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), ".pdf"), allow_redirects=True)
```

It's potentially the problem but I don't think.